# Implementing an "Add Company" section in a project

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-oriented, closure

I'm working on avoiding JavaScript that either directly modifies the DOM a ton, contains a ton of anonymous functions, or is encapsulated in giant `$(document).ready...` blocks.

This is one of my first attempts at writing a section of my project in a better way.  The code is commented and organized fairly well, so it should be easy to understand how it functions.  My main question is: **Am I going about this the right way?**

```
// Object literal for handling all aspects of adding a company
var addCompany = {

  // Initialize object
  init: function() {

    // Save elements references
    addCompany.elements = {
      openForm: $('#add-company-btn'),
      form: $('#add-company-form'),
      usernameField: $('#username'),
      usernameErrorField: $('#username-error div'),
      passwordField: $('#password'),
      passwordErrorField: $('#password-error div'),
      password2Field: $('#password2'),
      password2ErrorField: $('#password2-error div'),
    };

    // Run on click 
    addCompany.elements.openForm.click(
      addCompany.focusFirst
    );

    // Run on focus
    addCompany.elements.form.submit(
      addCompany.validate
    );
  },

  // Focus the first input field 
  focusFirst: function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      addCompany.elements.usernameField.focus();
    }, 0);
  },

  // Validate the form
  validate: function() {

    // Store the error tests
    var noUsername = (addCompany.elements.usernameField.val().trim() === ''),
        noPassword = (addCompany.elements.passwordField.val().trim() === ''),
        differentPasswords = (addCompany.elements.passwordField.val() !== addCompany.elements.password2Field.val());

    // Return the results of running the tests
    return addCompany.handleError(addCompany.elements.usernameErrorField, noUsername) &&
           addCompany.handleError(addCompany.elements.passwordErrorField, noPassword) &&
           addCompany.handleError(addCompany.elements.password2ErrorField, differentPasswords);
  },

  // Given an error, handle the display of error fields
  handleError: function(error_field, error) {
    if(error) {
      error_field.show();
      return false;
    } else {
      error_field.hide();
      return true;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going very well. There is nothing wrong with it, except there are some things that can be further improved. To improve it you can further do:

1. `addCompany` should be in pascal case i.e. `AddCompany`
2. Try to use `this` i.e. use `this.something` instead of using `addCompany.something` everytime.
3. Module name should be noun instead of word. You may use `Company` instead of `addCompany`
4. You can make the `private` properties using the following version of Modular Pattern:

   ```
   var Company = function () {

   // ------- Start #PrivateSection ------

   // Save elements references
   var elements = {
     openForm: $('#add-company-btn'),
     form: $('#add-company-form'),
     usernameField: $('#username'),
     usernameErrorField: $('#username-error div'),
     passwordField: $('#password'),
     passwordErrorField: $('#password-error div'),
     password2Field: $('#password2'),
     password2ErrorField: $('#password2-error div'),
   };


   // Given an error, handle the display of error fields
   var handleError = function(error_field, error) {
     if(error) {
       error_field.show();
       return false;
     } else {
       error_field.hide();
       return true;
     }
   }

   // ------- End #PrivateSection --------


   // Public Properties and methods
   return {
     // Initialize the object
     init : function () {
       bindUI();
     },

     // All the event bindings to go here.
     bindUI : function () {
       // Run on click 
       addCompany.elements.openForm.click(
         addCompany.focusFirst();
       );

       // Run on focus
       addCompany.elements.form.submit(
         addCompany.validate
       );
     },

     // Focus some element
     focusElement: function( el ) {

       var toFocus;

       // If no value provided
       if ( typeof el == "undefined" ) {
         // Focus the first element
         toFocus = elements.usernameField;
       } else {
         // Focus the provided element element
         toFocus = el;
       }

       toFocus.focus();
     },

     // Validate the form
     validate: function() {

       // Store the error tests
       var noUsername = (addCompany.elements.usernameField.val().trim() === ''),
           noPassword = (addCompany.elements.passwordField.val().trim() === ''),
           differentPasswords = (addCompany.elements.passwordField.val() !== addCompany.elements.password2Field.val());

       // Return the results of running the tests
       return handleError(elements.usernameErrorField, noUsername) &&
              handleError(elements.passwordErrorField, noPassword) &&
              handleError(elements.password2ErrorField, differentPasswords);
     }

   };
   };
   ```

And then to use it,

```
var c = new Company();
c.init();
```